# Jackson JSON: get node name from json-tree

Tags: java, json, jackson

How can I receive the node names from a JSON tree using Jackson?
The JSON-File looks something like this:

```js
{  
    node1:"value1",
    node2:"value2",
    node3:{  
        node3.1:"value3.1",
        node3.2:"value3.2"
    }
}
```

I have

```
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(fileReader);
```

and need something like

```
for (JsonNode node : rootNode){
    if (node.getName().equals("foo"){
        //bar
  }
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This answer applies to Jackson versions prior to 2+ (originally written for 1.8). See [@SupunSameera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18342245/139010) for a version that works with newer versions of Jackson.

---

The JSON terms for "node name" is "key." Since [`JsonNode#iterator()`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#iterator%28%29)
does not include keys, you need to iterate [differently](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fields%28%29):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> elt : rootNode.fields())
{
    if ("foo".equals(elt.getKey()))
    {
        // bar
    }
}
```

If you *only* need to see the keys, you can simplify things a bit with [`JsonNode#fieldNames()`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fieldNames%28%29):

```
for (String key : rootNode.fieldNames())
{
    if ("foo".equals(key))
    {
        // bar
    }
}
```

---

And if you just want to find the node with key `"foo"`, you can [access it directly](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#get%28java.lang.String%29). This will yield better performance (constant-time lookup) and cleaner/clearer code than using a loop:

```
JsonNode foo = rootNode.get("foo");
if (foo != null)
{
    // frob that widget
}
```

Comment: It looks as though `getFields()` changed to `fields()` in Jackson 2.0.0.

Comment: Iterating through `String key : rootNode.fieldNames()` gives me `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable` error. Any idea?

Comment: Actually iterating through `Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry : rootNode.fields()` also gives the same error for me

Comment: Given that both `fieldNames` and `fields` return `iterator`, which is [not iterable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598219/java-why-cant-iterate-over-an-iterator), the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18342245/3831137) seem to be the correct solution, which iterates using `hasNext`.

Comment: I use fasterxml 2.6.7 and all the iterator methods cause infinite loop.

Comment: 1. Try this http://pastebin.com/r85AXVm9. It prints "{"type":"http","http":{"binding":"text","url":"http://localhost:9992","httpHeaders":{"Content-Type":"text/plain"},"httpMethod":"GET"},"template":{"rtemplate":"R template","ptemplate":"P template"},"var1":"true","var2":"true"}" forever, instead of 2 times as it is supposed to.

Comment: 2. Try this: http://pastebin.com/KR5NKfqy It prints "id="first.item" indefinately.
3. This  "for (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> elt : rootNode.fields())"&"for (String key : rootNode.fieldNames())" do not compile. (foreach does not apply to java.util.Iterator)

Comment: I'm not sure if this was valid prior to Jackson 2+, but it definitely is not anymore (it doesn't compile). Though the gist is correct. But, you need to store off and use the Iterator directly. Fast enumeration works on Iterable objects, not Iterators directly.

Comment: @stuckj my original answer is over 5 years old at this point and has been edited multiple times to bring it up to date. And yes, it was originally written in reference to Jackson 1.8. :) Please do feel free to suggest another edit to improve the answer!

Comment: @MattBall Sure thing. Just having the version specified would be helpful. :) Edit coming...

Comment: @stuckj sorry the reviewers rejected your edit :( I edited myself. Thanks again!

Comment: is null check for elt variable needed  ?

Answer (score 85):

For Jackson 2+ (`com.fasterxml.jackson`), the methods are little bit different:

```
Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodes = rootNode.get("foo").fields();

while (nodes.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>) nodes.next();

  logger.info("key --> " + entry.getKey() + " value-->" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: This only iterates some of the nodes.  I'm seeing some nodes being skipped.

Comment: is null check for entry variable required here ?

Answer (score 15):

fields() and fieldNames() both were not working for me. And I had to spend quite sometime to find a way to iterate over the keys. There are two ways by which it can be done.

One is by converting it into a map (takes up more space):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> result = mapper.convertValue(jsonNode, Map.class);
for (String key : result.keySet())
{
    if(key.equals(foo))
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Another, by using a String iterator:

```
Iterator<String> it = jsonNode.getFieldNames();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    String key = it.next();
    if (key.equals(foo))
    {
         //code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me, all other suggestions were cause infinite loops.

Comment: I show that getFieldNames() should be fieldNames().

Answer (score 13):

Clarification Here:

While this will work:

```
 JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(file);
 Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = rootNode.fields();
 while (fields.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = fields.next();
    log.info(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue())
 }
```

This will not:

```
JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(file);

while (rootNode.fields().hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = rootNode.fields().next();
    log.info(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue())
}
```

So be careful to declare the `Iterator` as a variable and use that.

Be sure to use the `fasterxml` library rather than `codehaus`.

Comment: rootNode.fields() does not compile (Java 7)?

Comment: Then your version of the Jackson library does not support it.

Comment: This solution did not compile for me and in my ignorance, I downvoted it which I should not have done. I since learned via another post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54205005/how-to-read-the-root-nodes-when-they-only-have-a-value-using-jackson) that it was due to me using the older codehaus jackson when I should have been using the newer fasterxml. However, @ChrisGeo retaliated nastily: http://oi65.tinypic.com/dypp5k.jpg
Admin reversed his faux paus.

Comment: I tried a bunch of times but I get "You last voted on this answer yesterday. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.". Can you please edit to say you should use the new fasterxml version of jackson and not the codehaus?

Comment: Man you saved my day. Your `While this will work:` was exactly I was looking for and was struggling around that.

Answer (score 7):

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);
root.at("/some-node").fields().forEachRemaining(e -> {
                              System.out.println(e.getKey()+"---"+ e.getValue());

        });
```

In one line Jackson 2+

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: Well, the solution is obvious, what kind of description should he add?