# Is it reasonable to assume that all children of root node in Jackson are field names?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I am trying to iterate through JsonNode tree, and I have written a following snippet that iterate over children nodes of root node and gets the text out of it, which I assume will be a field name.

```
JsonNode rootNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonParser);
for (JsonNode node : rootNode){
    String fieldName = node.asText(); // <- is it safe to assume this?
    JsonNode value =  node.get(fieldName);
}
```

I have read [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653813/jackson-json-get-node-name-from-json-tree), but the accepted answer simply doesn't work because both `fields` and `fieldNames` return `iterator`, which cannot be iterated through a `foreach` loop just by itself [as far as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598219/java-why-cant-iterate-over-an-iterator).

The other most upvoted answer works, but I was wondering if the above snippet's assumption is still valid.

Comment: The accepted answer states _Since `JsonNode#iterator()` does not include keys_ with a link to the javadoc for more details.

Comment: If you're confused about the foreach statement, [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work) how it works in relation to `iterator()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The javadoc of [`JsonNode#iterator()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#iterator()) states

> Same as calling [`elements();`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#elements()) implemented so that convenience "for-each"
>   loop can be used for looping over elements of JSON Array constructs.

And the javadoc of [`JsonNode#elements()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#elements()) states

> Method for accessing all value nodes of this Node, iff this node is a
>   JSON Array or Object node. **In case of Object node, field names (keys)
>   are not included, only values.** For other types of nodes, returns empty
>   iterator.

So the elements returned are the values of each key-value pair of an object node. For array nodes, it's the array elements.

Comment: Hm that's a shame. I really liked how clean that code snippet looked. Also, I feel like I am missing a vital information about Java. Why was the original answer accepted if the `iterator` cannot be iterated through `for` loop?

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP I don't understand that last question. If a type implements `Iterable`, a value of that type can be used in a foreach statement.

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP Also, I realize now that the answer there already contains my answer.

Comment: In [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653813/jackson-json-get-node-name-from-json-tree), the accepted answer loops through `Iterator`, but I thought `Iterator` itself cannot be iterated through `foreach` loop as indicated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598219/java-why-cant-iterate-over-an-iterator). The class need to implement `Iterable` as you said, which is not guaranteed for either `fields()` or `fieldNames()` since they are simply `Iterators`, but do not necessarily implement `Iterable`.

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP So `JsonNode` implements `Iterable`. But, yes, you are correct about the others. You've posted a comment already. Matt is pretty active. They should be able to fix that. Otherwise, I will for them.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah sorry about the confusion. I meant to write `foreach` instead of `for` loop.