# In JsonParsing using Jackson, how to get all nodes with same name, but in different levels of hierarchy?

Tags: java, json

```
{
    "icon": "service",
    "title": "A",
    "type": "service",
    "children": [
        {
            "icon": "sharedlibraries",
            "title": "sharedlibraries",
            "type": "sharedlibraries",
            "children": [
                {
                    "icon": "war",
                    "title": "abc.war ( ui-shared-lib )",
                    "path": "abc/common/Services/1.2.0/lib/comp.war",
                    "reference": >"abc/common/templates/applications/11.1.2.3.jar/config/config.xml",
                    "type": "sharedlibrary",
                    "version": "11.1.2.0@11.1.2.0",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "icon": "jar",
                            "title": "comp1.jar",
                            "path": >"abc/common/SharedServices/1.2.0/lib/comp.war/WEB-INF/lib/comp.jar",
                            "reference": >"abc/common/Services/1.2.0/lib/comp.war/WEB-INF/lib",
                            "type": "jar",
                            "thirdpartyjar": "true"

                        }
                    ]
                },
:
:
:
}
```

I would need to retrieve, attribute "path", of all nodes with name "children", whose "thirdpartyjar" atribute= true. Is this possible using jackson?

Update: I tried following:

```
          public void parse(File file) throws JsonProcessingException, 
          IOException {
                   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                   //JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(file);
                   Model model = objectMapper.readValue(file, Model.class);
                   listThirdPartyJars(model);
                   while (true) {
                   Model children = model.getChildren();
                   if (!(children == null)) {
                         listThirdPartyJars(children);
                         model = children;
                   } else {
                         break;
                   }
                 }
                 }

            public void listThirdPartyJars(Model model) {
            boolean thirdPartyJars = model.isThirdPartyJar();
            if (thirdPartyJars == true)
                System.out.println(model.getPath());
      }
```

But, came across following exception:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.manager.Model out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: D:\my_json.json; line: 4, column: 22] (through reference chain: com.manager.Model["children"])

Comment: Have you checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653813/jackson-json-get-node-name-from-json-tree?rq=1)?

Comment: Please post a valid JSON.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin The JSON is a truncated one, posted in order to explain the question. Thanks

Comment: It's still invalid though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the JSON you posted in your question (with a few fixes to make it valid):

```json
{
  "icon": "service",
  "title": "A",
  "type": "service",
  "children": [
    {
      "icon": "sharedlibraries",
      "title": "sharedlibraries",
      "type": "sharedlibraries",
      "children": [
        {
          "icon": "war",
          "title": "abc.war ( ui-shared-lib )",
          "path": "abc/common/Services/1.2.0/lib/comp.war",
          "reference": "abc/common/templates/applications/11.1.2.3.jar/config/config.xml",
          "type": "sharedlibrary",
          "version": "11.1.2.0@11.1.2.0",
          "children": [
            {
              "icon": "jar",
              "title": "comp1.jar",
              "path": "abc/common/SharedServices/1.2.0/lib/comp.war/WEB-INF/lib/comp.jar",
              "reference": "abc/common/Services/1.2.0/lib/comp.war/WEB-INF/lib",
              "type": "jar",
              "thirdpartyjar": "true"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) and a query such as `$..children[?(@.thirdpartyjar=='true')].path` will do the trick and will give you the following result:

```json
[
  "abc/common/SharedServices/1.2.0/lib/comp.war/WEB-INF/lib/comp.jar"
]
```

You can test it [here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

### Using Jayway JsonPath

To use [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath), add the following dependency to your project:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then read the JSON document:

```java
String json = "...";
List<String> paths = JsonPath.read(json, "$..children[?(@.thirdpartyjar=='true')].path");
```

Alternatively to Jayway JsonPath, you can map your JSON to Java classes (or simply use the Jackson Tree Model), parse the JSON using Jackson, iterate recursively over the tree and extract the data you need.

Comment: Thanks . I am able to get correct output with jayway json filter expression "$..*.children[?(@.thirdpartyjar=='true')].path", in online jsonpath validator, but using java code, I am not getting any result. Any idea what may be wrong

Comment: Thanks @Cássio Mazzochi Molin!. It worked. I was using older json-path jar , and reading the input json file, directly , without parsing.

Comment: File jsonFile = new File("D://json//my_json.json");
List<String> paths = JsonPath.parse(jsonFile).read(
"$..*.children[?(@.thirdpartyjar=='true')].path");

Comment: is it possible, that we may get respective parent attributes along with children attributes? So the requirement is, getting 2 information: 1) Child jar relative path based on whether the same is a third party jar or not 2) Parent location hierarchy, till root . This information is there in the input json

Comment: @SoumaliChatterjee Instead of using a query to select a single property (such as `path`), you can use a query such as `$..children[?(@.thirdpartyjar=='true')]` then map the result to a Java bean and get the desired values. Check the documentation for extra details. If you have other question, you may want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it's possible. You would need to have a model which references itself as an attribute, somewhat like :

```
public class Model {
    String icon;
    String title;
    String path;
    String reference;
    String type;          
    String version;
    boolean thirdPartyJar;
    Model children;
    ...getters, setters and overriden methods
}
```

And you can map your Json string to this object using [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to further access the children with attribute `thirdPartyJar` as true.

Comment: public void parse(File file)  {
                       Model model = objectMapper.readValue(file, Model.class);
                        listThirdPartyJars(model);
                        while (true) {
                        Model children = model.getChildren();
                         if (!(children == null)) {
                                  listThirdPartyJars(children);
                                  model = children;
                          } else {
                                  break;
                         }
                        }

Comment: @SoumaliChatterjee Please don't post code in comments. Either update your question or ask a new one.