# Write stream of objects to file

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am trying to write a stream of custom objects with a nice toString method to a file, line by line. What I have so far is this:

```
private static void writeToFile(Set<Article> articles, Charset cs, Path path) throws IOException {

    try(Writer w = 
            new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(path.toFile()), cs))) {

        articles.stream().map(Article::toString).forEach(w::write);

    } catch(IOException e) {}
```

I am getting the error **Unhandled IOException** on w::write, which is strange because I am catching this Exception?

Other point, is it possible to write those objects line by line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8: How do I work with exception throwing methods in streams?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548589/java-8-how-do-i-work-with-exception-throwing-methods-in-streams)

Comment: They are actually very close, but the similarity is hidden.

Comment: @zwiebl It gives you the exact solution you need, you need to wrap the method call in the `forEach` in another method that catches the error, the outside try/catch won't catch an exception inside the forEach, just like his `throws` won't deal with his `Exception`.

Comment: what about the new line for every new object from the stream?

Comment: @zwiebl Don't ask compound questions. And of course, add a newline(`\n`) after each string.

Comment: this will create an extra line at the end...

Comment: Note that on *nix systems said trailing newline is the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach` expects a `Consumer<? super E>`, where `E` is the type of the `Stream`'s elements. The signature of `Consumer<T>::accept` is

```
void accept(T t)
```

Note how it does not throw any checked exceptions.

Now, `Writer::write` *does* throw a checked `IOException`, so when you do `.foreach(w::write)`, the compiler complains because you are trying to use a method that throws an exception (`Writer::write`), as one that doesn't (`Consumer<T>::accept`). In order to fix this, you have to handle the exception in the `foreach` itself:

```
articles.stream().map(Article::toString).forEach(str -> {
    try {
        w.write(str + System.lineSeparator()); // Add a newline to each string.
    } catch(IOException e) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Note that instead of writing from the stream, you can construct the entire `String` in memory and then write it all at once.

```
String data = articles.stream().map(Article::toString).map(str -> str + System.lineSeparator()).reduce("", (acc, str) -> str + acc)
w.write(data.substring(0, data.length()-1)); // Drop last newline
```

Answer (score 4):

`PrintWriter` is useful for cases such as this, as its methods don't throw `IOException`. It also has `print(Object)` overloads, which converting the object to a string via its `toString` method. (Really it calls `String.valueOf` which handles nulls before delegating to `toString`.)

Unfortunately `PrintWriter` is a somewhat old-fashioned API, as it takes a `File` instead of a `Path` and a charset name instead of an actual `Charset` object. But converting isn't too big a deal.

Since no intermediate `map` call is necessary to convert the object to a string, it's sufficient to call `forEach` directly on the collection.

Here's the resulting code:

```
static void writeToFile(Set<Article> articles, Charset cs, Path path) throws IOException {
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(path.toFile(), cs.name())) {
        articles.forEach(pw::println);
    }
}
```