# How to count the number of files in a directory, with the same file extension, in Java?

Tags: java, file, stream, filesystems, java-stream

I want to be able to count all the save games a user has created.

*Using Java, how can I count all the files in a directory with a specific extension?*

**This code counts all the files regardless of extension:**

```
public class MCVE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        countFiles();
    }

    private static void countFiles() {
        long amountOfFiles = 0;
        try {
            Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get("./saves"));
            amountOfFiles = files.count();
            System.out.println(amountOfFiles);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered iterating over the stream?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not a very experienced programmer, and I don't know anything about that.

Comment: Iterate through the stream and check with `getFileName()`

Comment: [How do I iterate over a stream in Java using for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044041/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-stream-in-java-using-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your extension in this function.

```
amountOfFiles = files.map(Path::toFile).filter(e->e.getName().endsWith(".xml")).count();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot get this to work. It always returns zero. I have tried with the ".sav" files I am trying to use, and a ".ttf" file I threw in there just to test with.

Comment: That it does! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure it out on my own. Since I couldn't figure out how to use the Path `endsWith()` method, I had to convert each Path object to a String, and then use the String version of the `endsWith()` method instead.

```java
private static void countFiles() {
    long amountOfFiles = 0;
    try {
        Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get("./saves"));
        Iterable<Path> iterable = files::iterator;

        String fileName = "";
        for (Path p: iterable) {
            fileName = p.getFileName().toString();
            if(fileName.endsWith(".sav"))
                amountOfFiles++;
        }

        System.out.println(amountOfFiles);

        files.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FilenameFilter` and `FileFilter` to filter you needed file or dirctory.

```
File file = new File("pathname");
// fileter file name start wit Chap
file.listFiles(pathname -> pathname.getName().startsWith("Chap"));
// fileter car read file
file.listFiles(pathname -> pathname.canRead());
```

You can refer to the official documentation [Java IO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)