# Java 8 stream to file

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have a `java.util.stream.Stream` of objects with some nice `toString` method:
What's the **shortest/most elegant solution to write this stream to a file**, one line per stream element?

For reading, there is the nice `Files.lines` method, so I thought there must be a symmetric method for writing to file, but could not find one.
`Files.write` only takes an iterable.

Comment: I can see there's a method [`Files#write(Path, Iterable<? extends CharSequence>, OpenOption ...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) that may help you.

Comment: Maybe create a <code>FileOutputStream</code> and then create a <code>PrintStream</code>?

Comment: @ downvoter: Care to explain?
@LuiggiMendoza: Yeah, I saw that too and edited my question already. That one only takes an iterable. Yes, I can convert, but I do not want to.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Probably the shortest way is to use [`Files.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) along with the [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130475/4856258) which converts the `Stream` to the `Iterable`:

```
Files.write(Paths.get(filePath), (Iterable<String>)stream::iterator);
```

For example:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("/tmp/numbers.txt"),
     (Iterable<String>)IntStream.range(0, 5000).mapToObj(String::valueOf)::iterator);
```

If it looks too hackish, use more explicit approach:

```
try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(
                     Paths.get("/tmp/numbers.txt")))) {
    IntStream.range(0, 5000).mapToObj(String::valueOf).forEach(pw::println);
}
```

If you have stream of some custom objects, you can always add the `.map(Object::toString)` step to apply the `toString()` method.

Comment: So how exactly does that work? How is an `Iterator` cast to an `Iterable`?

Comment: @knub, it's not an iterator, it's method reference to the `iterator()` method (I don't call the `iterator()` method, I create method reference instead). It's quite normal usage of method reference, which can be converted to the functional interface type.

Comment: Slightly cleaner
Iterable<String> source = stream::iterator;
Files.write(path, source);
 -- no casts, easier to grok what its doing at a glance

Comment: To clarify why a `PrintWriter` is created here (and not just a `Writer`): The methods in `Writer` all throw a checked `IOException`, which makes them annoying to use in `forEach`. On the other hand, `PrintWriter.println` throws no exception. Nice trick.