# why is it possible that the stream::iterator returns to Iterable in java?

Tags: java

I'm reading effective java and have one question.
I don't understand why the stream iterator returns to Iterable.
As I know, The Iterable contains the Iterator Interface.
But in stream api, this code is working, even though iterator doesn't inherit the Iterable.

```
    public static <E> Iterable<E> iterableOf(Stream<E> stream){
        return stream::iterator;
    }
```

I'm very confusing about this codes. Because there is no relation between Iterator and Iterable, excepting for that Iterable has Iterator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Stream<T> not implement Iterable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129762/why-does-streamt-not-implement-iterablet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Iterable<E>` is a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html#package.description). That means that any lambda meeting the criteria of its sole method, `Iterable<E> iterator()`, can act as an implementation of this interface.

That means that any lambda that takes no parameters and returns an `Iterator<E>` can be used as an instance of `Iterable<E>`.

Now, the notation `stream::iterator` is syntactic sugar for the lambda `() -> stream.iterator()`, which is a lambda that meets the above criteria. `stream::iterator` is thus a valid return value for a method that returns `Iterable<E>`.